# Windows cannot connect to Docker Window via container's IP

Tags: docker, networking

I was able to connect to my mssql-server-windows-developer until I went to mess with Hyper-V Manager's Virtual Switch. 
Here is how I create

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=saPwd123 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
```

Using docker inspect we can get the IP address of the container which is usually 172.17.xxx.xxx
From previous experience, we should be able to connect to that IP address.

This is my docker network list
[image]

[image]

I am connecting using SMSS via 172.17.33.26,1433.But the server couldn't be found.

May I know how can I reconfigure it back to the original state?

Thanks!

Comment: From where are you trying to connect? And what are you using for this connection?

Comment: Use `telnet` or other ways to first tell if the port is open. SMSS can fail for other reasons, but firstly you must confirm the port is opened.

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, I am connecting from my localhost where I installed my PC.

Comment: It shows this in kinematics when I tried to fun an image (HTTP code 404) no such container - network bridge not found

Comment: Try deleting the HYper-V VM and let docker recreate it and see if it helps?

Comment: Tried, from what I know Windows Container doesn't create a Hyper V VM right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue by:
1. Uninstalling Docker
2. Uninstalling Hyper-V from Control Panel 
3. Disable Hyper-V in BIOS 
4. Re-Enable Hyper-V in BIOS
5. Enable Hyper-V from Control Panel 
6. Reinstall Docker and switch to Windows Container. 
You should see both DockerNAT and HNS internal NIC.